# How do I apply italics to a tag inside an other tag in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child, value-of

I want to italicize the text between the  tags (see code below) of my xml file via xsl.
The `<stage>` tags are inside `<p>` tags. All text which is in `<p>` but not in `<stage>` should remain upright.

xml :

```
<div>
<sp>
    <p>Son cœur .... <stage>Chérubin arrache le ruban.</stage> Ah,
    le ruban!</p>
</sp>
</div>
```

As the `<stage>` tags are children of the `<p>` tags, I don't know how to apply the italics to the words "Chérubin arrache le ruban." only.

Here is the xsl I have tried for now:

```
<xsl:template match="div">   
    <xsl:for-each select="sp">
        <xsl:value-of select="speaker"/>
        <xsl:if test="stage!=''">
            <i><xsl:value-of select="stage"/></i>  
        </xsl:if>   
        <xsl:value-of select="p"/>      
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem with this is it only italicizes `<stage>` when it is outside the `<p>` tag, so in the example above it does not work.

I also tried using the substring-before/after method (https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1315438&seqNum=7) :

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '&lt;stage')" />
<i><xsl:value-of select="stage"/></i>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'&lt;/stage')" />
```

but still wasn't able to make it work.

Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is a template for `stage`:

```
<xsl:template match="stage">
  <i>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <i>
</xsl:template>
```

You can handle the other elements with separate templates, just make sure that the parent or ancestor templates keep processing child nodes by using `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.